# How to apply vector2s for direction/velocity of object

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a line segment that represents a direction and magnitude (length), when i draw the segment it works as it should. the value getAimArmsRotation is being pulled from another class that contains a touchpad value.

```
if (player.getFacingRight()) {
        lOriginX = (player.getPosition().x + Player.SIZEw/2);
        lOriginY = (player.getPosition().y + Player.SIZEh/1.5f);
        //lEndX = lOriginX + (float)Math.cos((player.getAimArmsRotation())/57) * 15f;
        //lEndY = lOriginY + (float)Math.sin((player.getAimArmsRotation())/57) * 15f;
        laserO = new Vector2(lOriginX, lOriginY);
        laserE = new Vector2(lEndX, lEndY);
```

However if I use the Vectors or floats from this calculation and apply them to a model's velocity vector it does not move the model along the line segment as I would think it should.

EDIT: Sorry meant to attach this picture when I created the question. Fig 1 is how my line segment looks, when I set the velocity values that make up the line segment to my object it moves in the direction that fig 2 shows.
[image]

getAimArmsRotation() is just a method that sets a sprite's rotation with a value from the touchpad in another class. I don't think that the values should matter since these floats are what i've used in order to give the line segment it's length and direction, I would think that giving an object a velocity of the x and y floats would give it the same direction as the line?

Comment: What, exactly, is it doing that you don't expect? What DO you expect? You might also post some code fom `getAimArimsRotation` for troubleshooting.

Comment: Have updated the question @JeremyScoggins

Comment: Please put some more code or some results. It's probably a precision issue due to the trigonometric operations, etc... Try tracking the values of lEndX and lEndY and compare between what they are and what they should be.

Comment: i think the most simple way would be creating a Vector normalize it and just use the x and y values to update it by multipling with the velocity and the deltatime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the DV, jerks.

I wasn't taking into account the origin position of the object when trying to send it along the desired path. I was only using the LineEnd values, I needed to give the object it's origin point to correctly calculate the trajectory or path.

```
for (GameObject go: gObjects) {
            if (go.getType() == PROJECTILE_ID) {
        go.getVelocity().x = player.getLineEndX() - player.getLineOrgX();
        go.getVelocity().y = player.getLineEndY() - player.getLineOrgY();
        System.out.println(go.getVelocity().x);
        System.out.println(go.getVelocity().y);
            }
        }
```